# Raphael animation recursion partially not accessing updated global variable

Tags: javascript, recursion, raphael, variable-assignment

I have two animations of for the same circle simply getting big then small. This repeats until a timer runs out. This works. They're defined recursively, a bit out of my league. The problem is getting it to change the speed while animating. I've removed the irrelevant code, including the timer, and simplified the interface to three buttons:

1) starts /stops

2) speeds up

3) slows down

It works for changing the inner defined function, but not the outer. I can't figure out **WHY**. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Please note my comment, which **SOLVES** it.  My understanding of computer science principles is not amazing.  I tried using Chrome's inspector to view the stack, but couldn't see anything, and wouldn't know what I was doing anyways.

```
var IN_DURATION = 3000;   
var OUT_DURATION = 5000;

var anim_inhale = Raphael.animation({
    transform: "S " + 2.2 + " " + 2.2 + "  T +"+(-320*2.2)+" "+(-240*2.2),
    fill: "#0f0"
}, IN_DURATION , "linear", function () {

    breath_circle.animate(Raphael.animation({
        transform: "",
        fill: "#00f"
    }, OUT_DURATION , "linear", function () {

        breath_circle.animate(anim_inhale);

    }));

});
breath_circle.animate(anim_inhale);
```

I've provided a working JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nastajus/RgWbL/2/

Comment: My friend showed me, he solved it instantly. All he did was just add  `console.log(anim_inhale);` then looked in Chrome Inspector seeing [this](http://i.imgur.com/9Ogdk35.png), then proceeded to add code `anim_inhale.ms = IN_DURATION;` which fixed it.  Updated JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nastajus/RgWbL/5/). 

So this solves the short-term problem but I still want to understand why for the future.